# How to ensure that chaincodes managed by different organizations remain compatible

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In the car lease demo, the national regulator owns and operates a chaincode that corresponds to a "car" object. It defines relevant attributes and its lifecycle. Everyone is always on the same page and life is beautiful.

But, to me, it appears inevitable that we will soon see an explosion of "Car" chaincodes by:

- other countries with their regulators
- insurers that come up with their own blockchain solution
- individual car manufacturers that want to capture more attributes of their cars on a blockchain
- etc

Unless there is a way to link these different "Car" chaincodes, a Car manufacturer will quickly find itself having to integrate into dozens of different blockchain networks which might not always be in sync with each other.

With my Object-Oriented background it seems obvious that it would be very valuable if the concepts of subclasses or interfaces could apply here. The insurer could define a "Car" interface and every manufacturer that  implements that interface in their own "Car" chaincode could automatically be plugged into the insurers solution.

But I don't think such concepts exist in Hyperledger Fabric.

So, hence my question: what are the best practices to ensure chaincodes managed by different organizations can talk to each other in such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite an old question. But the idea would be that the insurer would create a chaincode for a "Car" with certain methods which can then be invoked by the manufacturers without the manufacturer having to create any chaincode themselves.